# Failed to load user into session with

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

For some reason, testing my **authentication**, I created a user with the login **8===D**, and **password 123**, and then `passportjs` says it fails to serialize that user when i try to login, however do it with any regular like username like **bill@kentucky.com** then it works fine and serializes the user on login. I can provide code as a example as well, but does it have do with it having strange characters(**like '='**)?

Also why can I serialize with just `.id` instead of `._id`, why does that work? I use mongoDB and it always generates a `_id` instead.

```
exports.postLogin = function(req, res, next) {

  // Do email and password validation for the server

  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    if(!user) {
      req.flash('errors', {msg: info.message});
      console.log("ERROR BOYS");
    }
    // Passport exposes a login() function on req (also aliased as logIn()) that can be used to establish a login session
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      console.log("User: " +user + " has been logged in");  
      if(err) return next(err);
      req.flash('success', { msg: 'Success! You are logged in'});
      res.end('Success');
    });

  })(req, res, next);

};


/**
 * GET /logout
 */
exports.getLogout = function(req, res, next) {
  // Do email and password validation for the server
  console.log("You have been logged out");
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
};

/**
 * POST /signup
 * Create a new local account
 */
exports.postSignUp = function(req, res, next) {
  var user =  new User({
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    profile: {
      firstName : req.body.firstName,
      lastName : req.body.lastName,
      section : req.body.section
    }
  });
  User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function(err, existingUser) {
    if(existingUser) {
      req.flash('errors', { msg: 'Account with that email address already exists' });
      res.redirect('/sign');
    }
    user.save(function(err) {
      if(err) return next(err);
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        console.log('Successfully created');
        console.log('Printing user');
        console.log(user);
        console.log('Print our body from our request');
        console.log(req.body);
        res.redirect('/');
        res.end();
      });
    });
  });
};
```

And the `serialize` part:

```
/* Initializing passport.js */
var User = require('../models/user');
var local = require('./passport/local');


/*
 * Expose
 */
module.exports = function(app, passport, config) {
  // serialize sessions
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });

  //use the following strategies
  passport.use(local);

};
```

Maybe it has to do with the login??::???

```
else {
      renderedResult = (
       <div>
  <div className={styles['wrapper']}>
  <div className={styles['container']}>
    <h1 className={styles['welcomelogin']}>Welcome, If ya just signed up then go ahead and sign in</h1>
    <fieldset className = {styles['loginSet']}>
      <input type="text" className = {styles['form-control']} placeholder="Username" ref = "email" name = "email" />
      <input type="password" className = {styles['form-control']} placeholder="Password" ref = "password" name = "password" />
      <button type="submit" className={styles['login-button']} to = "dashboard" onClick={this._onLoginSubmit}>Login</button>
    </fieldset>
    <hr/>

<p>Need an account? <Link to="register">Signup</Link></p>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
);
    }}
  return (
    <div>
  {renderedResult}
  </div>
      );
  }
}
```

User Model:

```
/**
 * Defining a User Model in mongoose
 * 
 */

var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var crypto = require('crypto');

// Other oauthtypes to be added

/*
 User Schema
 */

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true},
  password: String,
  tokens: Array,
  profile: {
    firstName: { type: String, default: ''},
    lastName: {type: String, default: ''},
    gender: { type: String, default: ''},
    location: { type: String, default: ''},
    website: { type: String, default: ''},
    picture: { type: String, default: ''},
    section: { type: String, default: ''}
  },
  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordExpires: Date,
  google: {},
  isStaff : { type: Boolean, default: false}
});


/**
 * Password hash middleware.
 */
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;
  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();
  bcrypt.genSalt(5, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});

/*
 Defining our own custom document instance method
 */
UserSchema.methods = {
  comparePassword: function(candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if(err) return cb(err);
      cb(null, isMatch);
    })
  }
};

/**
 * Statics
 */

UserSchema.statics = {}



module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: Hahahahaha that user.

Answer (score 1):

Serialize function determine what data from the user object should be stored in the session. The result of the serializeUser method is attached to the session as `req.session.passport.user = {}` here for instance it would be(as we provide id as key)

```
    req.session.passport.user = {id:'xyz'}
```

> Passport will serialize and deserialize user instances to and from the
>   session.
>   In this example, only the user ID is serialized to the session,
>   keeping the amount of data stored within the session small. When
>   subsequent requests are received, this ID is used to find the user,
>   which will be restored to `req.user`.
>
> The serialization and deserialization logic is supplied by the
>   application, allowing the application to choose an appropriate
>   database and/or object mapper, without imposition by the
>   authentication layer.
>   http://passportjs.org/docs

Basically, you need to  work around with this, transforming those `=`in html code or not allow these symbols. Just remember that the session is converted in strings with `&` and `=`. Like :

```
data=data&data2=data2
```

Comment: It feels silly though, at isoreports.kkotwal.me, there is a demo of me doing it before, and I can create that user with that type of username. The code for that project is here: https://github.com/kkotwal94/IsoReportProcessor. So why would it be any different?

Comment: I will look at it will take some time. I guess you are missing the user model with username being an email pattern. That's why you can't create the account. Post the user model file or check that guess.

Comment: Ive added the user model, and it probably isn't much of a big deal. I was just wondering why.